# Index being redirected to Show View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes

When I go to /relationships/index it displays the show page even if it is not mentioned in the controller?  Then when I try to just go to an index view without a show page created I get the following error: Unknown action: The action 'show' could not be found for relationships controller, even with no mention of it in the controller or a view file for the action.

routes.rb

```
Mymanual::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :validation_rules

  resources :validations

  resources :product_types

  resources :products

  resources :connections

  resources :relationships

  root :to => 'products#index'
end
```

relationships_controller.rb

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def new
        @relationship = Relationship.new
    end
end
```

Then just HTML in a index.html.erb, show.html.erb and new.html.erb file.

Comment: I don't see what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `/relationship` path is for `relationships#index`. If you go to `/relationships/index`, Rails router assumes you want to go to `relationships#show` path with `params[:id] == 'index'`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you want the `index` action, you don't enter `index` in the url. Otherwise, it thinks you're trying to find a `Relationship` with an id of `index`.

So just go to `/relationships` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Go to a console and then run:

```
rake routes
```

It will give you all routes your app understand

In some place of this routes you will have something like:

```
relationships    relationships#index  /relationships
relationship     relationships#show   /relationships/:id
```

The issue that you have is that the app understand **/relationships/index** as relationships with **id=index**

The fix?  use `/relationships` url